# Transform tagged to CSV

Tags: python, xml, csv

A file like this:

```
fieldname_A: eggs
fieldname_B: bacon 
~EOR~
..
..
~EOR~
fieldname_A: eggs
fieldname_C: spam
fieldname_Z: baked beans
~EOR~
```

in total, 40 different field names, about 10,000 records (EOR is End Of Record) with a variable set of fields in them. Most field content is short, some is very long (over 1000 characters).

I'm looking for a nice, clean, pythonic way to transform this to CSV, or rather, to a Google spreadsheet. (The data needs to be checked and corrected. Several people will do this. A google doc is the only fast way I know for them to work on the same data without causing version conflicts or syncing problems.)

Dictwriter seems like a cumbersome way, because many records (ie rows in a the spreadsheet) have fields in them that are empty.

The form of the input file is more XML-ish, so I'm thinking to transform it to XML, import that into Excel, and then upload it as Google spreadsheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the fieldnames known up-front?

Comment: `DictWriter` can be told to use a default value for missing entries in a row.

Comment: Last but not least, one end-of-record line has `~EOR` while all the others all have `~EOR~` (note the second tilde). Is that a typo on your part?

Comment: @Martijn Yes, field names are known up front; type ~EOR~ corrected, thank you :-) ; and yes, you are correct in assuming no data rows will have EOR in it.

Comment: For your data cleaning, investigate "Google Refine" (now apparently being renamed to "OpenRefine").

Answer (score 1):

Use this one...

```
infile = "d.txt"
data = open(infile, "r").readlines()

dataDict = []
columns = []

rowData = {}
# Create a dictionary list
for line in data:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    if "~EOR~" in line:
        keys = rowData.keys()
        dataDict.append(rowData)
        columns = list(set(columns) | set(keys))
        rowData = {}
    else:  
        cell = line.split(":", 1);
        print cell
        rowData[cell[0].strip().strip('"').strip("'")] = cell[1].strip().strip('"').strip("'")


# Write dictionary list to file
outfile = "d.csv"

with open(outfile, "w") as fp:

    columns.sort()

    for key in columns:
        fp.write(key + ", ")

    fp.write("\n")

    for data in dataDict:
        for key in columns:
            if key in data:
                fp.write(data[key] + ",")
            else:
                fp.write(",")
        fp.write("\n")
```

Input:

```
fieldname_A: eggs
fieldname_B: bacon 
~EOR~
fieldname_A: eggs
fieldname_C: spam
fieldname_Z: baked beans
~EOR~
```

Output:

```
fieldname_A, fieldname_B, fieldname_C, fieldname_Z, 
eggs,bacon,,,
eggs,,spam,baked beans,
```

Comment: use `.split(':', 1)` to only split on the first colon; that way values can have a colon in them and still be parseable. Blank lines are easy to skip.. `if not line.strip(): continue`.

Comment: Testing for `line.strip() == '~EOF~'` shouldn't be hard, of course, removing the last assumption. The assumption is then that `~EOF` without trailing tilde is an error in the question, and not a correct example of the file format. Or test for `line.strip() in ('~EOF', '~EOF~')`..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks a bunch! I'll try this. Will let you know results

Comment: @all Guys, you're all bewdiful, it works like a charm. I turned the separator into a pipe, as lots of lines contained comma's and semicolons. 
I like the subtle 'print cell' too. Some fields turn out to have quadruple hard returns in them. I need to replace those anyway (had done single, double and triple). The split will crash on the violating lines.